# using LocalStorage to store data

Tags: react-hooks, local-storage

I am working on building an expense tracker using react. I want to save the entered inputs using localStorage. I have tried the below way but seems getItem() is not working as expected. The input is gone after refresh. Below is the code snippet

```
    import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import Expenses from "./components/Expenses";
import NewExpense from "./components/NewExpense/NewExpense";
const dummyExpenses = [
  {
    id: "e1",
    title: "Toilet Paper",
    amount: 94.12,
    date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
  },
  { id: "e2", title: "New TV", amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
  {
    id: "e3",
    title: "Car Insurance",
    amount: 294.67,
    date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
  },
  {
    id: "e4",
    title: "New Desk (Wooden)",
    amount: 450,
    date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
  },
  {
    id: "e5",
    title: "internet",
    amount: 400,
    date: new Date(2021, 3, 12),
  },
];

//Rendering items using localstorage.getItem

const local = localStorage.getItem('expenses')
? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expenses'))
: dummyExpenses
const App = ()=>{
  const [expenses,setExpenses] = useState(dummyExpenses,local);
  const addExpenseHandler = expense =>{
    setExpenses(prevExpenses=>{
      return[expense,...prevExpenses];
    });
    //console.log('In App.js');
    console.log(expense);
  };

//saving items using localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify(expenses))
  }, [expenses])
  return (
    <div>
      <NewExpense onAddExpense = {addExpenseHandler}/>
      <Expenses items = {expenses}/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I am using getMonth() to filter the expenses month wise, and on just using local in useState is rendering the below error
'TypeError: expense.date.getMonth is not a function'

Expense component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Expenses.css";
import ExpensesFilter from "./ExpenseFilter";
import ExpenseList from "./ExpenseList";

function Expenses(props) {
  const [filteredMonth, setFilteredMonth] = useState(" ");
  const FilterChangeHandler = (selectedMonth) => {
    //console.log(selectedYear);
    setFilteredMonth(selectedMonth);
  };
  const FilteredExpenses = props.items.filter((expense) => {
 
    return expense.date.getMonth().toString() === filteredMonth;
  });
 
  return (
    <div className="expenses">
      <ExpensesFilter
        selected={filteredMonth}
        onChangeFilter={FilterChangeHandler}
      />
      <ExpenseList items = {FilteredExpenses} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Expenses;
```

Comment: Do you wanna try using a `useLocalStorage` hook instead which somewhat functions like `useState`. Example here: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

Comment: `useState` only takes one argument, so the second argument you are giving is ignored. Try `useState(local)`.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie, I tried giving useState(local). Getting an error '×
TypeError: expense.date.getMonth is not a function'

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie, I tried giving useState(local). Getting an error '×
TypeError: expense.date.getMonth is not a function'

I am using getMonth() to filter expenses according to month
i have added the expense component as well above

Comment: Yes, this is because you cannot store Date objects in local storage, you can only store serialized data. Try to turn the dates into strings using `toISOString` before the serialization, and turn them back into dates after parsing.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie thank you so much! Can you please show in code.. It would be helpful